# Multi-threading for ListView makes wrong items / no items at all appear

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, concurrency, android-asynctask

I am working on an App in which I have a ListView with a lot of images. To ensure a smooth user experience I followed this lesson from Android Developer: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html . I implemented the Concurrency Handler exactly as described there (as far as I can tell), yet it does not work very well. It does a reasonable job when the user simply flings the ListView, but **when the user flings the ListView and suddenly stops it, the wrong images appear or sometimes no images appear at all**. My code to load the images in the background is:

```
public class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

private final WeakReference<ImageView> mImageViewReference;
private int mData = 0;


public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
    // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
    mImageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

// Decode image in background
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    mData = params[0];

    ...

    if (mLruCache.getBitmapFromMemoryCache(key) != null) {
        bitmap = mLruCache.getBitmapFromMemoryCache(key);
    } else {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MyApp/" + key + ".png", options);
        mLruCache.addBitmapToMemoryCache(key, bitmap);
    }

    return bitmap;
}

// Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isCancelled()) bitmap = null;

    if (mImageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = mImageViewReference.get();

        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

public static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    private static WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> mBitmapWorkerTaskReference;

    public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap, BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
        super(res, bitmap);
        mBitmapWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(bitmapWorkerTask);
    }

    public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
        return mBitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
    }
}

public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(int data, ImageView imageView) {
    BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

    if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
        int bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.mData;
        if (bitmapData != data) {
            // Cancel previous task
            bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
       if (imageView != null) {
           final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
           if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
               AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
               return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
           }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the getView() method of my adapter I have:

```
// Load images in the background
int data = position;
if (BitmapWorkerTask.cancelPotentialWork(data, imageView)) {
    BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
    BitmapWorkerTask.AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new BitmapWorkerTask.AsyncDrawable(mContext.getResources(), null, bitmapWorkerTask);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
    bitmapWorkerTask.execute(params);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always hard to get it right... Why don't you just use [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) ?

Comment: I'm trying to use UniversalImageLoader but I get the error: `UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/mnt/sdcard/MyApp/211.png]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))`. Do you perhaps know how I use getStreamFromOtherSource(...)?

Comment: Nevermind, after reading the documentation more carefully I found out I just needed to add `"file://"` to my path.

Comment: UniversalImageLoader works great by the way, thanks a lot for the suggestion!